# Is there any limit on the number of repositories in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to find out if there are any limits on the number of repositories we can create in Gerrit ?

Comment: Why would you believe there is such limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit on the number of Gerrit repositories. Take a look at the [Gerrit Scaling Documentation](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/homepage/+/md-pages/docs/Scaling.md) to get more info about this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no limit for the number of repos in Gerrit. Maybe have a look at [OpenStack's installation](https://review.openstack.org/#/admin/projects/), they have a decent number of repos.